# Relationship between AlarmManager and application life

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Does the the AlarmManager stop working after the application is dead?
If not so, why is it stopping in my application?
In my application, a new alarm is created at the service which is started from `AlarmReceiver` class. This `AlarmReceiver` class extend `BroadcastReceiver`. In this way after reciving a alarm a new alarm is created. But this process is working properly as long as the app is not dead. But I want this process to continue beyond that. How can.I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is dead nothing works ...

So for your application to have less probabilities to be killed by the system your service should call startForeground() and display a non-dismissable notification.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: But if somehow the app is killed is there any way to start the alarm again automatically?

Comment: Yes, the system will try to restart the service if service onStartCommand() returns START_STICKY;